# How to display longer Name inside the Card only using CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js, ecmascript-6

[image]

1. In this image i want to display entire text inside card body only, But the text is showing ..pqrst.....

Comment: Share your html and css for the parent (card) element and anything inside it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code may work:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;  // if your parent has finite width
    max-width: 100%; // if your parent has finite width
```

If your parent don't have fixed width then you may have to use px values.

Answer (score 0):

CSS: by tweaking the overflow and white-space property. Try this:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

It should show the entire name on one line. Ellipsis "..." should also be removed

Comment: Not if the parent element has a finite width.